# With W3 Total Cache when I publish a post it does not appear in the homepage. Only if i purge all cache

Tags: plugins, posts, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

If you go to the ps4 page you will see that the last post is there

[My Site](http://gamersaction.com/)

Is it necessary to do something for the post to appear on the homepage or should it appear by default?

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using browser caching ? Therefore new visitors would see the newly published post just fine,  but because you've previously visited the page its cached and therefore your browser cache hasnt expired.

Generally its good practice to clear all caches upon publishing posts/pages and/or activating or deactivating a plugin.

You can also disable page caching for the front page :

```
performance - page cache -  Don't cache front page
```

Comment: How can i automatically clear all caches when a post is published?

Answer (score 0):

You can set auto purge whenever you publish or update a post.
However its better to purge all cache as you might know whats not working post publishing/updating content.

If you are using W3 Total Cache plugin on WP site, this can be done from WP Dashboard -> Performance -> Page Cache -> Purge Policy: Page Cache -> Front page, Posts page, Post, page, Blog feed -> Save changes.

Comment: How can i set to auto purge?